# Importing python packages into node files

Tags: ros, rospy, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set up my ROS package with the following layout:

```
packagename
  CMakeLists.txt
  package.xml
  |- src/
    |- packagename/
      |- __init__.py
      |- package_file.py
  |- scripts/
    |- node_file.py
```

And in `node_file.py`, I'd like to be able to do

```
from packagename import package_file
```

But I get `cannot import name package file`.

Am I laying this out correctly? How do I make my python package visible to `node_file.py`? I am using ROS Hydro in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151951/importing-python-packages-into-node-files/) by [kamek](https://answers.ros.org/users/3942/kamek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't realize that I needed a `setup.py` file at the root of my package (I previously thought this was only needed for installing packages). I was used to using Fuerte where this was unnecessary. See here for how to create and use this file:

http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile

---

Originally posted by [kamek](https://answers.ros.org/users/3942/kamek/) with karma: 79 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on 2014-07-18**:
Setup.py is very important, and should probably be added to the python publish/subscribe tutorials.